# Likert scale with linear form input control

Tags: likert, scales, calibration

If I want to collect the **order of agreement** with a statement in a questionnaire, I’d traditionally use an ordinal Likert scale, most likely with classic 5 points, but maybe 4, 6 or 7 and perhaps with an `N/A` option.

Let’s assume, though, that I want to use these ordinal values only at the backend, i.e. when analyzing the data, but **present a linear input** to the people filling out the electronic form, e.g. a slider widget.

[image: radio group vs. slider vs. number input, with 0 for “completely disagree” through 4 for “completely agree”]

This control could easily allow for arbitrary precision, but let’s just say it is only near-linear with 100 steps for my 5 Likert values.

How can and should I calibrate such an input scale to output data for each individual?
I could ask neutral control questions or I could normalize by assigning min response = 0 (or 1), max = 4 (or 5) and med or mid = 2 (or 3).

I assume that, overall, a linear input yields more reliable results than a discrete one, even if the data is still analyzed on a short ordinal scale. Is there any research to back up or refute this hypothesis?